# Niedrig hängende Früchte

Tags: word-usage, anglicism

Auf [www.spiegel.de](http://www.spiegel.de) las ich soeben die [Frage](https://www.spiegel.de/auto/claudia-kemfert-zum-klima-urteil-kommt-der-verbrennerausstieg-a-c0d95738-de3c-4c69-b4dd-45012b4dea49)

> Gibt es im Verkehr niedrig hängende Früchte, mit denen man die Emissionen schnell senken kann?

Das englische "[low hanging fruits](https://de.ryte.com/wiki/Low_hanging_fruits)" wird seit Längerem im Management- und Berater-Jargon verwendet.

Meine Frage: Ist die Redewendung "niedrig hängende Früchte" ein neu entstandener Anglizismus oder wurde sie auch früher schon im Deutschen verwendet?

Comment: The phrase "low hanging fruit" started growing in popularity 25-30 years according to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=low+hanging+fruit&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#). A similar search for niedrig/tief hängende Früchte says 20-25 years, though to me the numbers aren't big enough to be statistically significant. Does the German expression *leichte Beute* mean about the same thing?. My research suggests there's not much danger of it being replaced.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=niedrig+h%C3%A4ngende+Fr%C3%BCchte%2Ctief+h%C3%A4ngende+Fr%C3%BCchte&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cniedrig%20h%C3%A4ngende%20Fr%C3%BCchte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctief%20h%C3%A4ngende%20Fr%C3%BCchte%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cniedrig%20h%C3%A4ngende%20Fr%C3%BCchte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctief%20h%C3%A4ngende%20Fr%C3%BCchte%3B%2Cc0) the link for "a similar search" mentioned in the previous comment. The encoding of the German in a URL made it too long to fit.

Comment: @RDBury Die Quantität der Suchergebnisse bei ngram sagt erstmal nichts über die Verwendung aus und hilft wenig bei der hier gesuchten Antwort. Dazu müsste man sich viel eher die verlinkten Quellbücher anschauen und nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen der Botanik suchen. Die Beantwortung solcher Fragen ist aber eh immer schwer, denn wie beweist man, dass etwas "nicht" da war. Da wäre in dem Fall viel im Trüben fischen drin. Die Frage ist auch wann der Begriff im Englischen entstand und ab wann eine deutsche Quelle als "früher" gelten kann.

Comment: @mtwde: Yes, the NGram results are, at best, suggestive rather than conclusive. To me, what was more interesting (again, not conclusive) was how few results for *hängende Früchte* there were compared to the apparently home-grown German expression *leichte Beute*. I'm wondering why anyone would feel the need to import a phrase from English when there seems to be a perfectly fine domestic version.

Comment: @RDBury I do not think that *leichte Beute* has exactly the same meaning as *niedrig hängende Früchte* although there is a certain resemblance. I think the English phrase *low hanging fruit(s)* was adopted, without translating it, by management consultants and  managers in German companies, probably because it sounds smarter than old-fashioned German phrases. I heard it for the first time approx. 15 years ago.

Comment: I've seen *leichte Beute* translated as "easy prey" in English, which is not the same as "low-hanging fruit", but in the sense of gains achievable with little time or effort I think they're similar enough. Management consultants do bring in a lot of new words and expressions into English, often because they "sound smarter", so I suppose it follows they have similar influence on German.

Comment: @RDBury It seems to me that "easy prey / leichte Beute" has a negative connotation because it is frequently used in the context of criminal activities. [Example](https://beatties.com/blog/2017/06/05/hackers-target-small-businesses/): In fact, SMBs are frequently targeted by hackers as easy prey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es dürfte schwer nachzuweisen sein, welchen Weg das Idiom genommen hat. Die Suche nach "hängende Früchte" in den verschiedenen DWDS-Korpora vermittelt aber den Eindruck, dass es im Deutschen neu ist.

https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=h%C3%A4ngende%20Fr%C3%BCchte

In den Korpora, die vor 2000 enden, ist "niedrig hängende Früchte" oder "tief hängende Früchte" überhaupt nicht zu finden. In den Zeitungskorpora fehlt bei den frühsten Fundstellen online leider der Kontext, der erste Eintrag, der das Idiom klar im heutigen Sinn einsetzt, ist aus der ZEIT im Jahr 2000:

Die Zeit, 23.11.2000, Nr. 48

> Zumindest so lange nicht, wie mit dem neuen Instrument die "tief hängenden Früchte" geerntet werden, so der Umweltschützerjargon.

Hier wird also noch davon ausgegangen, dass das Idiom bei den Lesern nicht bekannt ist.

Wirklich mehr wird es dort erst ab 2010.

Comment: Danke für die Forschungsarbeit, die das relativ geringe Alter des deutschen Begriffs belegt. Eine Google-Suche nach "niedrig hängende Früchte" ergibt 480.000 Treffer, nach "low hanging fruit" dagegen 56.500.000 Treffer. Das spricht für den englischen Ursprung.

Answer (score 0):

Die Redewendung dürfte aus dem Englischen entlehnt sein.

1. Wie HalvarF in seiner Antwort ausführt, ist der deutsche Ausdruck "niedrig hängende Früchte" vor dem Jahr 2000 praktisch nicht zu finden.
2. Insbesondere dieser [Artikel](https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/business/trends-and-insights/articles/the-history-of-jargon/) unterstützt die Vermutung, dass der Begriff aus dem Englischen stammt:

> "Low-hanging fruit" refers to what's easily achievable without much effort. This expression first appeared as early as the 17th century in various poetic or literary works as a vivid metaphor. According to Investopedia, the exact phrase "low-hanging fruit" likely first appeared in print in a 1968 article in the Guardian newspaper, gaining popularity in the following decades, and "becoming a staple in corporate management and sales lingo" by the early 1990s. It even appeared in a 2009 [Dilbert cartoon](https://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=low+hanging+fruit) as an example of "the vacuous way managers speak."

> In 2016, writer Zack Crockett authored an article on Priceonomics showing the explosion in usage of this expression. But his research shows that the expression has now become totally irrelevant by the change in apple tree genetics grafting. When the expression was first popularized, the majority of apple trees were tall and the only fruits that were easily within reach were those that hung low on the branch. But today, as Crockett writes, the majority of apple trees are dwarfs.

> Yet another reason for abandoning this stale buzzword.

3. Wie der OP in einem Kommentar zu  HalvarFs Antwort feststellt, liefert eine Google-Suche  nach "low hanging fruit" ca. hundert Mal so viele Treffer wie der Suchbegriff "niedrig hängende Früchte".
4. Meine eigene Erfahrung bestätigt eine Beobachtung des OP, er habe das *englische* "low hanging fruit(s)" erstmals vor ca. 15 Jahren in Vorträgen von Unternehmensberatern bzw. Managern gehört (s. Kommentar zur Frage). Ich selbst habe "low hanging fruits" erstmalig ca. 2010 im Zusammenhang mit einem Reorganisationsvorhaben von einem hochrangigen Manager in meinem Unternehmen gehört, der auch das gleichermaßen beliebte Wort "Synergien" im Munde führte. Das deutsche "niedrig hängende Früchte" ist mir dagegen erstmalig in dieser Frage untergekommen.

Lesenswert im Zusammenhang mit Punkt 2 ist auch [dies](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/low-hanging-fruit.asp).

Comment: heruntergewählt für die Verkettung mit Investipedia. Entweder fasse den Inhalt hier zusammen oder lass den Link aus.

Comment: @vectory Nur interessehalber: Welches der Kriterien in https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down ist hier erfülllt?

Comment: der erste. dabeiist es hinreichend egal ob es war oder nur nach Spam aussieht, jedenfalls solange es nicht auszuschließen ist, ohne dem Link tatsächlich zu folgen. Davon abgesehen gehört eine Zusammenfassung einfach zur üichen Praxis, am Maßstab guter Antworten gemessen.

Comment: @vectory Das erste wäre dann "incorrect" : Downvote answers that are incorrect or don't provide sufficient information to be useful in answering the question. Some answers may not attempt to answer the question at all, and should be flagged.

Comment: Ich bin mir abersicher da stand noch "spam" als ich es las